# Guidelines for types of questions

Tags: discussion, guidelines

I understand that there are different desires for what types of questions this community should be addressing. It is dificult to know when a question does not fit. Is there a guidelines somewhere?

Comment: Yes, right where you'd expect to find them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's usually covered in that site's **Help → Tour**. (Menu at very top of page.)

Comment: *Help* > *Help Center* also works.  In fact the first entry is about what type of questions are appropriate.